# save audio file in raw or assets folder to sdcard android

Tags: android, audio, android-file

Hi guys i am having a audio file in assets folder and i need to save the same file onto sdcard .

How to acheive this.

Below is the code i am using to save file

```
String filename = "filename.txt";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] data = new String("data to write to file").getBytes();
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
InputStream path = mngr.open("music/music1.mp3"); 

                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(path,1024);

                    //get the bytes one by one
                    int current = 0;

                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {

                        baf.append((byte) current);
                    }
}
byte[] bitmapdata  = baf.toByteArray();
```

After converting into byte array copy this into the sdcard as follows

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), music1.mp3);
FileOutputStream fos;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bitmapdata  );
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);

Comment: hey here in File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), music1.mp3); music.mp3 it showing error

Comment: hey thanks i got it can you please explain me what is happening in the code please

Comment: u are opening the file present in assets folder and read it to a byte array and the same byte array you are writing into the newly created file in sdcard

Comment: why is byte array required her please explain

Comment: in general to read and write into a file  using of bytearray is the best

Comment: Seems like ByteArrayBuffer does not persist anymore since org.apache.http is removed.