# Right place for putting mp3 files in an android project

Tags: android, mp3

Is there any folder like res/drawable for mp3 or generally audio files? If yes, what is it and how can I get access to it from the app?

Comment: you can use either raw folder or asset folder........ for raw refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499605/how-to-play-the-audio-files-directly-from-res-raw-folder for asset refer this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493983/save-audio-file-in-raw-or-assets-folder-to-sdcard-android also refer difference between Asset & Raw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/android-difference-between-res-and-assets-directory

Comment: Raw resources are not compressed or manipulated in any way when packaged into your application, making them an ideal way to store precompressed files such as audio files.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The best place to put such `.mp3` or any other files would be in the `assets` folder.

These files once stored will become a part of your android app itself and can be read easily. This [tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) describes it well.

```
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
 player.prepare();
 player.start();
```

Alternatively you can also store it in the `raw` folder and read it directly by specifying the path as the raw folder.
this can be played as:

```
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
```

Comment: Assets or RAW ? just let me know a specific answer

Comment: I followed the asset option with some luck. I added a flag to this code to keep from replaying the mp3 every time a play button was clicked.

Comment: I place files in RAW folder.

Comment: I was wondering if we can initially make a database and store the files in the database itself?

Comment: @juztcode No, It's not recommended to put files in database (For example it will cause increasing db size and as a result will slow down loading db).

Comment: Difference between the raw folder and the assets folder:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563373/when-should-i-use-the-assets-as-opposed-to-raw-resources-in-android

Answer (score 13):

Here are some steps you can easily follow.

1. Open the android studio with the project in which you want to add-on audio clip/media file.
2. Create a `raw` folder in the resources folder.
3. Add media file to the `raw` folder by simply copy and paste that to the `raw` folder.
4. Here we added a media file “ring.mp3”. Now open the Java File of the desired activity, here we are adding the audio in the MainActivity.
5. Further add this code.

   `MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ring);`
   `ring.start();`
6. **Now run the App and your music will play when App starts**

Comment: okay i follow your tips here.

Answer (score 7):

You should save the .mp3 into `res/raw`. AndroidStudio recognizes the `raw` folder. (By contrast, it does not automatically recognize a `res/assets` folder).

To play music.mp3:

`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.cat_meow);
mediaPlayer.start();`

Note the convenient use of `R.` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Place it into your assets folder. Preferably under assets/raw/myfile.mp3
You can access it using:

```
String mp3File = "raw/music.mp3";
AssetManager assetMan = getAssets();
MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
FileInputStream mp3Stream = assetMan.openFd(mp3File).createInputStream();
media.setDataSource(mp3Stream.getFD());
media.prepare();
media.start();
```

Comment: This is not working. Perhaps assets/ should be removed from the path.