# How do I create a URI to the application res directory

Tags: android

I have some music file under the following relative path:

```
    Main Project Directory\app\src\main\res\music
```

What how do I create an URI to point to it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such files should be into `raw` directory or `assets` directory, not into `res` directory. Read more about [`Providing Resources`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

[Right place for putting mp3 files in an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959554/right-place-for-putting-mp3-files-in-an-android-project) is a good example to read such files from `assets`/ `raw` directory.

Comment: @Downvoters : It would be very helpful if you post a comment about the reason of your priceless downvote :)