# SetDataSource in MediaPlayer class to load up an mp3 file from Assets or raw folder

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the code for playing a `mp3` file from a `path`. I although don't know what the value of my `filePath` should be when I call `StartPlayer(String filePath)`.

My audio files stored are in the `assets` and `raw` folders. But I don't know what the best place for storing the audio files are? Also, I am not sure how to access the path from either of the folders.

```
protected MediaPlayer player;

public void StartPlayer(String  filePath)
{
  if (player == null) {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
  } else {
    player.Reset();
    player.SetDataSource(filePath);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it required for you to use a `string` as the parameter? Could your solution possibly work using the name of the file instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you add your media file as an asset, you need to use the `AssetManager` to get an `AssetFileDescriptor`. An instance of the `AssetManager` is available by accessing the Assets property on an `Android.App.Context`, such as an `Activity`. So in an `Activity` sub-class, you can do the following in your `else` clause:

```
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = Assets.OpenFd("filenameinAssetsfolder.mp3");
 player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.Reset();
 player.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor);
 player.Prepare();
 player.Start();
```

However I do have to say that your audio will not play the first time due to your `else` clause, which will not run when the MediaPlayer is null when that method is called. Seems you should just do this:

```
 if (player == null)
 {
      player = new MediaPlayer();
 }
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = Assets.OpenFd("filenameinAssetsfolder.mp3");
 player.Reset();
 player.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor);
 player.Prepare();
 player.Start();
```

For more info on the AssetManager: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/

Comment: This plays the last song in the Asset folder, I didn't have mentioned that I have multiple songs in the Asset folder.

Comment: I found the solution        player.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffSet, afd.Length);

Comment: Please accept an answer even if it helped you find the solution. In this case the answer did show you how to find files in the assets folder so you can work with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the `assets` and `raw` folder to store audio files which will be compiled with your .APK.

But you should re-consider your strategy in regards to using a `filePath` as your parameter. Instead, consider using a `string fileName` or an `int resource`.

To retrieve a file from the `assets` or `raw` folder cannot be done using a `filePath` in Android. Instead, this is done by either using the `AsssetManager` or through a `Resource` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959588/2399772).

I have also optimised your code a little as the `else` clause isn't needed.

## Assets folder

When trying to access a file from the `assets` folder, you need to use the static method `OpenFd` from `this.Assets` (where `this` is the `Context` of your `Activity`) with the name of the file. This will return an [`AssetFileDescriptor`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor/) that you can use as a `DataSource` as follows:

```
protected MediaPlayer player;

public void StartPlayer(string fileName)
{
    if (player == null) 
        player = new MediaPlayer();

    var fileDescriptor = Assets.OpenFd(filename);

    player.Reset();
    player.SetDataSource(fileDescriptor.FileDescriptor);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
}
```

## Raw folder

You can also use the `raw` folder which although requires that you point to the auto-generated `id` of the given `Resource`. This is done using the static `Create` method of the `MediaPlayer`:

```
protected MediaPlayer player;

public void StartPlayer(int resource)
{
    if (player == null) 
        player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, resource);

    player.Reset();
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
}
```

Where `resource` refers to the audio file in the `raw` folder which can be accessed by `Resource.raw.youraudiofile` (where `youraudiofile` is the name of the audio fie in the `raw` folder).

You can read more about using the `raw` folder in [the Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/).